# Python: subtracting 2 already defined variables in a function

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I seem to have having an issue with While Loops...

```
while True:
leave=input("\n"
           "\nDo you..."
            "\n"
            "\nA: Leave the ship and go out into forrest"
            "\nB: Stay in the ship and sleep through the night"
            "\n"
            "\n: ")
if leave.lower()in ("a","leave","leave the ship"):
    leaveA=("\n"
            "\nYou slowly make your way out through the hole"
            "\nand you slide down the ship. Once you reach the"
            "\nyou start to make your way through the dense"
            "\nforrest. As you make your way through the woods"
            "\nYou start to hear faint voices from your right."
            "\n")
    for char in leaveA:  # applying to each character
        time.sleep(0.01)  # the time delay
        sys.stdout.write(char)  # adding the typing effect
        sys.stdout.flush()
    health-=injure
    injury()
    print("\n"
          "\n-----Statistics-----"
          "\n"
          "\nHealth:", health,
          "\nEnergy:", energy,
          "\nArmour:", armour,
          "\nStamina:", stamina,
          "\nStrength:", strength,
          "\nAccuracy:", accuracy)


    flee=input("\n"
               "\nThis leaves you with two choices..."
               "\n"
               "\nA: Move towards the voices, in hopes that they will help 
                you."
               "\nB: Run back to the ship to look for a weapon to defend 
                 yourself."
               "\n"
               "\n: ")
```

My problem is that if you choose option A in leave it never breaks so the loop will loop back to leave and if I break after the if statement the code will never reach the flee input. What I'm trying to do is to have option A in leave lead to flee and option B lead to something else I have later in the code. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds (and looks) like indentation problem.

Comment: Please correct your indentation, it is not clear what is inside the loop and what is outside.

Comment: Not sure I follow leave A and flee both are in the same indent and are under the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To help you solve your problem, allow me to present you the general strategy about how to go about this or many, many, many other problems:

Use the "divide and conquer" strategy:

You have a system that is consisting of multiple parts and the system doesn't work as expected. What do you do? You take each part and ask yourself: can I take this part away, without destroying the one function of the system that I am trying to get to work (that is not working now)?

If you can answer that question with "yes, I can take this away", then do so. That will reduce your problem and make it easier to understand until you ultimately have only those parts before you that are **necessary**.

Applied to your problem at hand: there are many lines of code, that server no purpose in the essential function your are trying to get to work.

The 'print("Statistics")' statement f.ex. can be dropped, it serves no purpose in your quest to get the **loop** working correctly.

Go ahead with this strategy and you should end up with a **much** shorter program in which you'll be able to spot the root problem at a glance.